# How do I register for push notifications in watchOS with SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, push-notification, watchos

This is my App:

```
import SwiftUI
import UserNotifications

@main
struct FieldService_Watch_AppApp: App {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
                TabView {
                    TimerView()
                    ContentView()
                    CategoriesView()
                        .environment(\.managedObjectContext, manager.defaultContext)
                    ServicesView()
                        .environment(\.managedObjectContext, manager.defaultContext)
                    FirstView()
                }
                .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { phase in
            if case .active = phase {
                Task {
                    await loadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func loadData() async {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        do {
            try await center.requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .sound, .alert])
        } catch {}
    }
}
```

Where do I setup it actually? Where can I add function similar to `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and there register for push notifications, and then add callback function like `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)`.

Comment: Have you found solution for this?

Comment: yes, you need to create delegate for it and conform to protocol delegate there.